# Is an insert and a corresponding trigger call an atomic process?

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I have a table called `LOCK` and I want to ensure that not more than a single row with a given name and type `WRITE` exists. Though multiple rows with type `READ` and an equal name are allowed but only if there is no row with the same name and type `WRITE`.

```
create table "LOCK"
(
    "LOCK_ID" NUMBER(19,0) NOT NULL,
    "NAME" VARCHAR2(255 CHAR),
    "TYPE" VARCHAR2(32 CHAR),
    CONSTRAINT "SYS_LOCK_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("LOCK_ID")
);
```

Inserting a row has to be atomic, for instance no query with a following insert depending on the result of the query (because it could have changed meanwhile).

To ensure atomicy I created a trigger to check the initially mentioned condition (raising error on fail), which is occasionally ending up in various invalid states like two `WRITE` rows.

If inserts are executed sequentially the trigger works perfectly which leads to the assumption insert + trigger is no atomic process and if so, is there a safe way to solve my issue?

Here's the trigger:

```
create or replace trigger "LOCK_TRIGGER"
before insert on "LOCK" 
referencing NEW AS NEW
for each row
declare
    c   integer := 0;
begin
    select count(*) into c from "LOCK" where (:NEW.typ = 'WRITE' and name = :NEW.name) or (:NEW.typ = 'READ' and name = :NEW.name and typ = 'WRITE');
    if (c > 0) then
        raise_application_error(-20634, 'Nope!');
    end if;
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trigger doesn't help here for the multiuser environment. You need to serialize the access to the particular lock name. For this case I would go for the custom locks. The database package dbms_lock is used for this. You can create a function which does the following:

1. acquires custom lock for the incoming name - this lock should be created with an option that it is not released on commit/rollback
2. makes the validation in the table for the name
3. inserts the record if possible (if validation passed) and commits it
4. releases custom lock
5. returns the result (either OK or NOK)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, this is exactly what i tried at first. The problem is, that I'm still able to insert a Write-Lock when there are Read-Locks and vice versa.

Comment: So new WRITE lock can be created when there is no locks with that name - neither READ nor WRITE. And READ lock can be created in the case when there is no WRITE lock for that name. Is this correct ?

Comment: Updated the solution.